# Using python-pptx package to append a table row will add a row that when edited in PowerPoint changes content of another row

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am using the python-pptx package to read a PowerPoint presentation into Python. There isn't native support to insert a row (or column) onto a table object. Although many individuals, per GitHub thread below have come up with a similar workaround to this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.table import _Cell

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')
TAB = prs.slides[1].shapes[1].table
copy_idx=0
insert_idx=1
new_row = copy.deepcopy(TAB._tbl.tr_lst[copy_idx])
for tc in new_row.tc_lst:
    cell = _Cell(tc, new_row.tc_lst)
    cell.text = 'foobar'
TAB._tbl.append(new_row)
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/pull/399

When you then open the PowerPoint presentation, if you click in the row added and begin typing, it will modify the text in the 1st row, not the newly added row. Saving, and restarting the application makes the issue go away. However this isn't good enough when I need to keep working on the Presentation object in python without having to stop to manually reboot PowerPoint.

Comment: I should add in case it wasn't obvious. That test.pptx is a simple 2 slide powerpoint with a table on the 2nd slide, hence the TAB object explicitly specifying slides[1].shapes[1] to identify that table.

Comment: Do you really have to restart PowerPoint? See if just saving, closing the file, and then reopening that file does the trick. How does the XML of that table (`TAB._tbl.xml`) change after you open and save it in PowerPoint?

Comment: Sorry, to be more precise in my language it's not a restart of PowerPoint required, but yes I need to open the file in PowerPoint and save it before I can edit it correctly. The `TAB._tbl.xml` doesn't change if I just save the ppt file. It does change if I save the ppt file, then load `prs = Presentation('test.pptx')` again. An extract of the change is <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="991783017"/> becomes <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="2914417793"/>

Comment: Can you post something like a diff with a little context so I can see where those were? A couple lines on each side should do the trick.

Comment: Of course, thanks. The context is the powerpoint is a simple 1 slide 'title and content' layout with a title that says 'Slide' and a 1x2 table with cell text saying B1 and B2 respectively. After running the add_row function (in question) there is another table row with text in each cell saying - (I changed it from foobar).

Comment: The TAB._tbl.xml is too long to paste. **It starts with**: '<a:tbl xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">\n  **and ends with** <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="1313612701"/>\n      </a:ext>\n    </a:extLst>\n  </a:tr>\n</a:tbl>\n'. **The only thing that changes upon saving is** that final val="1313612701" value.

Comment: I inspected this closer. It's because doing copy.deepcopy(TAB._tbl.tr_lst[copy_idx]) doesn't actually copy all attributes correctly. For example: Tab._tbl.tr_lst[0].nsmap.r is missing. Equally Tab._tbl.tr_lst[0].row_idx was equal to 3 originally, in the deepcopy it equals {str} "Traceback (most recent call last:\n File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/ ...then a long file path". I also can't do tc.row_idx = 4 because tc.row_idx hasn't got a setter. @scanny

Comment: Hello, does anybody have found a solution for the problem?